# Ruby to_s conversion to binary argument error

Tags: ruby

I was trying to solve a HackerRank problem which requires binary manipulation. The test cases are extremely huge numbers so I thought better to manipulate them as strings.

```
t=gets
def winner(pturn)
  if a%2==0 
    puts "Richard\n"
  else 
    puts "Louise\n"
  end
end            

while t != 0
    turn=1
    n=gets
    (n2=n).to_s(2)
    while n!=1
        one="1"
        zero="0"
        if n2.count(1)>1
            zero*=(n2.length - 2)
            one.concat(zero)
            n-=one.to_i(base=2)
        else
            n/=2
        end
     turn+=1
     end 
winner(turn)
t-=1
end
```

It caused an argument error (wrong number of argument) in line as seen below.

```
(n2=n).to_s(2)
```

I think I'm using `to_s` wrongly. I can't see the mistake and need someone to point it out.

Comment: I don't think to_s entertain any args.

Comment: What is that code supposed to do?

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli: `Integer#to_s` (or more precisely, the pair of [`Bignum#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Bignum.html#method-i-to_s) and [`Fixnum#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s)) accepts an optional `base` argument that tells it in which base you want to print the number. The default value is `10`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who tried to help me. What I don't understand was the input the I get for n is a number, and n2 is basically n. So the type should be a fixnum no? If it is a fixnum why isn't the to.s working when it works for things like 5.to_s(2) ?

Comment: @sawa Was away just now but I've edited the question a bit... The program is supposed to calculate who is the final winner. It starts off with a number (very huge), minus number by the next largest power of 2 if the number is not a power of 2. Else, reduce it by half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to convert a number in Ruby to a string with it's binary representation. This is possible with (if the number is actually a number in Ruby, e.g. Fixnum) :

```
4.to_s 2
# => "100"
```

But in your case, what you are getting after calling `gets` is a string, and the `to_s` method of the String class simply returns itself, and doesn't take any arguments, hence the error.

You can fix it by calling `gets.to_i` instead of just `gets`, so the read string of contents will be converted to an integer in Ruby (you should be sure that you will only be reading numbers at there).

And I believe you are trying to assign the binary representation (as a string) of `n` into the variable `n2`, for that you should be doing

```
n2 = n.to_s(2)
```

If you just do :

```
(n2=n).to_s
```

Because of the parenthesis, first `n2` will be assigned the value of `n`, then `to_s` will be called on `n2`, the string version of `n2` will be returned, and nothing else happens. First thing you should be doing is the conversion, then the assignment.

And also you should pass in a string while calling String#count, i.e. you should call `n2.count('2')` instead of `n2.count(2)`.

Comment: @idkwhatamidoing: `gets` is short for "get string". What did you think it would return? :)

Comment: So `gets` actually takes input as strings? Thanks, this is really helpful! Also, isn't `count()` a predefined method? I'm getting an `undefined method` error for the `count()`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Whoops yeah, didn't think of it. Is there no way to get an input as integer directly? Sorry I'm too used to language with strong types.

Comment: @idkwhatamidoing: no language with strong types will get you an integer "directly". Console input is text by nature. All you can do is interpret the string when you get it (parse as integer or whatever)

Answer (score -1):

Argument error is coming because you are trying to pass parameter to **to_s** method because to_s method never accept any arguments.

So you should change (n2=n).to_s(2) to

```
(n2=n).to_s
```

Comment: `Integer#to_s` (or more precisely, the pair of [`Bignum#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Bignum.html#method-i-to_s) and [`Fixnum#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s)) accepts an optional `base` argument that tells it in which base you want to print the number. The default value is `10`.

Comment: But if I change it to (n2=n).to_s how will the program know I want to change it to base 2?